# Silent Install Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8

Tags: windows, sdk, automation, windows-server-2012, silent-installer

I am writing my first Powershell script to automate the installation of Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.  I plan to install it on a Hyper-V VM running on Windows Server 2012. I have the .exe file (sdksetup.exe) necessary for the install.  I've looked into answer files, but it seems they require a disc.  I need to be able to press "Next" a few times, uncheck some preset boxes, and agree to a EULA, all automatically. I am fine with the default location of installation as well.  It seems so simple, yet I haven't found any really good resources on the web yet.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to consider moving this question to the Super User SE site.

Comment: I've never used that site, what's the URL?

Comment: http://superuser.com/, or just scroll down here on SO and you will find it under "Technology"